# Base SAS certificate sample: merge and in

Tags: merge, sas

What is the right selection for this problem and why? Thanks:

---

```
Given the SAS data set WORK.EMP_NAME:

  Name  EmpID
  ----  -----
  Jill   1864
  Jack   2121
  Joan   4698
  John   5463

Given the SAS data set WORK.EMP_DEPT:

  EmpID  Department
  -----  ----------
   2121  Accounting
   3567  Finance
   4698  Marketing 
   5463  Accounting
```

The following program is submitted:

```
 data WORK.ALL;
     merge WORK.EMP_NAME(in=Emp_N) 
           WORK.EMP_DEPT(in=Emp_D);
     by Empid; 
     if (Emp_N and not Emp_D) or (Emp_D and not Emp_N);
 run;
```

How many observations are in data set WORK.ALL 
after submitting the program?
         A. 1 
         B. 2 
         C. 3 
         D. 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Answer will be **B.2** 2 observations with 3 variables already, so new dataset *ALL* will have observations what are not neither in EMP_NAME or EMP_DEPT column  EmpID . Library actually is WORK for all.

*This statement does show that to merge only observations that are **not** common/present in EmpID when merging.
Emp_N is from first dataset and Emp_D is from second dataset.*

```
by Empid; 
 if (Emp_N and not Emp_D) or (Emp_D and not Emp_N);
```

***Hope it helps with the details bellow:***

```
 title "stackoverflow merge EMP_DEPT";
data work.EMP_NAME;
input Name $ EmpID;
datalines;
Jill   1864
Jack   2121
Joan   4698
John   5463
;
run;


proc print data = work.EMP_NAME;
run;


title "stackoverflow merge EMP_DEPT";
data work.EMP_DEPT;
 input EmpID  Department $ ;
 datalines;
2121  Accounting
3567  Finance
4698  Marketing 
5463  Accounting
;
run;

proc print data = work.EMP_DEPT;
run;


*merge;

data WORK.ALL;
 merge WORK.EMP_NAME(in=Emp_N) 
       WORK.EMP_DEPT(in=Emp_D);
 by Empid; 
 if (Emp_N and not Emp_D) or (Emp_D and not Emp_N);
 run;

 proc contents data=work.ALL;

 run;

 proc print data = work.ALL;
 run;
```

[image: result of merge]

Comment: Then the by clause is overridden by the if clause? Thanks.

Comment: After BY statement, there is a Subsetting IF Statement. So only the observations which satisfy the _subsetting IF statement_ are written to the output data set.